# Why does introducing more variational parameters improve the accuracy of our approximation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, variational-principle, approximations, molecular-dynamics

If we consider the variational method in quantum mechanics as outlined in this wikipedia article:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variational_method_(quantum_mechanics)

It is stated  that 'Some choices of ansatzs wave functions lead to better approximations than others, therefore the choice of ansatz is important.'

An indicator of how good our ansatz and approximation is how low the upper bound approximation for energy is, whereby the lower the approximation value for energy is then the closer it is to the true value.

I have been told that by choosing an ansatz with a greater number of variable parameters will result in a lower energy and thus better approximation. My question is why is this the case?

Comment: If you take an anstaz, and add one additional real free parameter, in general tuning in one way will cause the variational energy to increase, and tuning it the other will cause it to decrease. Hence, by tuning in the right direction you can lower the energy. There's nothing deep about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course it is possible to use a model with $k$ degrees of freedom, which does not properly describe a dataset, while a model with $p<k$ degrees of freedom performs much better. Thus, the statement is not true in general.

> Example: Think of a polynomial of order $n\ge4$, which is used to describe an exponential decay, in contrast to $A e^{-\lambda t} + \textrm{offset}$, or have a look at the image below.

However, the statement is true, if we consider two polynomials of order $n$ and order $k<n$: The polynomial with the larger order will in general produce a fit with a smaller (or equal) mean squared error,
$$\textrm{MSE} = (fit - data)^2 =\sum_i \left(y_i^{(fit)} - y_i\right)^2$$
This is obvious, because the additional coefficient are at worst zero, and thus dropping out.
In fact in statistics it can be shown that the mean squared error can be written as bias and variance -- which is often called the **bias-variance trade-off**. Therefore, the more flexible your model is the lower the deviation between data and fit.

However, we are ultimately **not** interested in fitting the data at hand, but we are interested in obtaining a model, which is able to predict new data. In statistics this leads to the concept of penalizing the number of fit parameters.

> Example: If we have $n$ data points (with different $x$ values), we know that a polynomial of order $n$ can  be used to produce a fit, which goes through every datapoint. However, since the polynomial does not only reproduce the "general trend" but incorporates the noise of the dataset as well, the fit is usually not accurate in describing/predicting new datasets. We say that the "high variance" fit is overfitting the dataset
> [image]

Comment: This is a very nice explanation of the bias-variance tradeoff, but I think it's somewhat orthogonal to the original question. In the quantum mechanical variational method, you aren't trying to *fit data*, but find a global minimum of the energy.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is generally true, but not strictly *guaranteed* to be true (unless you place some more constraints on how you are allowed to introduce the new parameter).

The basic premise of the variational method is that *any* state (besides the ground state itself) will have a higher energy than the ground state. What this means in practice is that if you have a given ansatz, and then you add new parameters and minimize the energy with respect to these parameters, you expect you can only get closer to the true ground state, or at worst stay the same as where you were before. This is certainly true if your original parameter space is a subset of the larger parameter space. However, that isn't guaranteed to be the case mathematically, so I think you could construct pathological examples where adding a new parameter makes things worse.

Having said that, adding more parameters is not guaranteed to help "very much," and each parameter will increase the cost and complexity of minimizing the energy. Therefore in practice, using a good guess with a few well-motivated parameters, is almost always better than randomly guessing functions with a zillion parameters.

Some more explanation...

Let $|0\rangle$ be the *true* ground state. Let $|\psi(\vec{\theta})\rangle$ be our variational state, where $\vec\theta$ refers to an array of parameters that we will vary. We can expand $|\psi(\vec{\theta})\rangle$ in the energy eigenbasis...

\begin{equation}
|\psi(\vec{\theta})\rangle = a_0|0\rangle + \sum_{n>0}a_n |n \rangle
\end{equation}
where $|0\rangle$ is the ground state (which we will assume is unique), and $n$ is a generic label that labels all the other energy eigenstates (which by definition have higher energy than the ground state). We assume that $|\psi(\vec{\theta})\rangle$ is normalized, so $|a_0|^2+\sum_{n>0}|a_n|^2=1$.

Then the expectation value of the energy is

\begin{eqnarray}
\langle \psi(\vec{\theta})| \hat{H} | \psi(\vec\theta) \rangle &=& |a_0|^2 E_0 + \sum_{n>0} |a_n|^2 E_n \\
&\geq& |a_0|^2 E_0 \sum_{n>0} |a_n|^2 E_0 \\
&=& \left(|a_0|^2 + \sum_{n>0} |a_n|^2\right) E_0 \\
&=& E_0
\end{eqnarray}

Therefore the variational strategy is to vary $\vec{\theta}$ and find the minimum of $\langle \psi(\vec{\theta})| \hat{H} | \psi(\vec\theta) \rangle$. The goal is to find the lowest possible minimum.

If we do this with some parameters and find a minimum $E_\star$ at $\vec{\theta}=\vec{\theta}_\star$, then by adding a new parameter $\alpha$ and minimize with respect to $\vec{\theta}$ and $\alpha$, we would intuitively expect that the new minimum is less than or equal to $E_\star$. This is certainly true if there is a value of $\alpha$ where $\alpha$ "drops out" of the expression for $|\psi(\vec{\theta})\rangle$, since then you know there is a point where the energy is equal to $E_\star$ within your parameter space, so of course the minimum must be at least as small as $E_\star$.

But this isn't *mathematically guaranteed* to be the case, at least without specifying some restrictions on how you are allowed to expand the parameter space... As a somewhat silly/contrived pathological example, let's suppose we introduce a parameter $\alpha$. We then choose a single parameter $\lambda$ from the set $\vec{\theta}$ which we suppose is bounded from -1 to 1, and let $\lambda_\star<1$ be the value of $\lambda$ when we minimize the energy using the variational wavefunction *without* $\alpha$. Now we replace $\lambda$ with $\frac{(1-\lambda')}{2}\tanh(\lambda/\alpha)+\frac{1}{2}(1+\lambda')$ everywhere it appears in $|\psi(\vec{\theta})\rangle$, where $\lambda'$ is some number $\lambda_\star<\lambda'<1$. Then the enlarged and modified parameter space no longer includes the point we previously called $\lambda_\star$, so the minimum energy will be larger.